# How to stop sending notification to Carbon Copy Recipientswhile we send the envelope for sign?

Tags: docusignapi

I have created envelope template and I have added one Signer Recipients and Two Carbon Copy Recipients.

When I send the envelope for signing then Docusign also send the notification to the Carbon Copy Recipients.

I want to send the notification only once the Signer Sign the envelope.

Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to establish a routing order.

By having the signer in routing order 1 and the CC recipients in routing order 2, the CC recipients will only receive notification once the signer has completed their role.